# Xcodebuild export ipa from xcarchive for enterprise

Tags: export, xcode7, xcodebuild, ipa, xcarchive

Two days ago it worked well.

But right after *June 22 4pm UTC+3* export fails with the error - "**error: exportArchive: No applicable devices found.**"
I read every article, every post about this error, but nothing is related to mine one.
I do not have rvm installed, I don't have CFPropertyList gem on my Mac at all except that one in a Xcode.app inside OS X SDK.

I know a little Ruby and can't figure out how to debug this error and where this gem can be.
Do you know how to fix it?
I can't even understand what did broke export ipa for an enterprise - nothing was installed new on this build agent, just regular code update from the repository.

---

I use Xcode Version 7.3.1 (7D1014) with same version of command line tools.
I do not use fastlane. Bitcode is enabled.
Export to app-store works well.

xcodebuild command line:

```
$ xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportOptionsPlist /Volumes/Agent/work/52b14e8c26a910b4/sources/myapp/Application/ExportOptions.plist -archivePath /Volumes/Agent/work/52b14e8c26a910b4/Artifacts/myapp-enterprise-1.0.0.362.xcarchive -exportPath /Volumes/Agent/work/52b14e8c26a910b4/Artifacts/myapp-enterprise-1.0.0.362.ipa
$ cat /Volumes/Agent/work/52b14e8c26a910b4/sources/myapp/Application/ExportOptions.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>teamID</key>
    <string>U****9****</string>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>enterprise</string>
    <key>uploadSymbols</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Full error log:

```
[16:36:00][Step 2/2] + xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportOptionsPlist /Volumes/Agent/work/52b14e8c26a910b4/sources/myapp/Application/ExportOptions.plist -archivePath /Volumes/Agent/work/52b14e8c26a910b4/Artifacts/myapp-enterprise-1.0.0.362.xcarchive -exportPath /Volumes/Agent/work/52b14e8c26a910b4/Artifacts/myapp-enterprise-1.0.0.362.ipa
[16:36:01][Step 2/2] 2016-06-24 16:41:22.239 xcodebuild[56839:14600947] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/5s/c4by9tm914nc_m4g7bylplwm0000gn/T/myapp_2016-06-24_16-41-22.239.xcdistributionlogs'.
[16:36:01][Step 2/2] 2016-06-24 16:41:22.258 xcodebuild[56839:14600947] [MT] DeveloperPortal: Using pre-existing current store at URL (file:///Users/buildserver/Library/Developer/Xcode/DeveloperPortal%207.3.1.db).
[16:36:01][Step 2/2] ** EXPORT FAILED **
[16:36:01][Step 2/2] 
[16:36:01][Step 2/2] 2016-06-24 16:41:22.773 xcodebuild[56839:14600947] [MT] IDEDistribution: Step failed: <IDEDistributionThinningStep: 0x7fa43ac7fea0>: Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=14 "No applicable devices found." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No applicable devices found.}
[16:36:01][Step 2/2] error: exportArchive: No applicable devices found.
[16:36:01][Step 2/2] 
[16:36:01][Step 2/2] Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=14 "No applicable devices found." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No applicable devices found.}
```

Comment: have you a fix for that? i have the same problem with Xcode 8 and commandline xcode build and my setting is the same as yours no fastlane no rvm

Comment: Unfortunately no, I use other build agents and they works just fine. Nobody can understand what was broken inside this agent.

Comment: i have found also an solution i make the build with Xcode 8 than i switch the commandline tools back to XCode 7.3.1 and export the archive to an enterprise ipa

Comment: Try this if above answer can't fix your problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/43419887/1982185