# xcodebuild exportArchive: no applicable devices found

Tags: ios, xcode, enterprise, xcodebuild

After upgrading to Xcode 8 with iOS 10, I get exactly this error. I am on latest El Capitan and using the following versions of ruby (I updated via rvm, same with 2.0.0 which is system version) and CFPropertyList:

```
Philipps-MacBook-Pro:mobile-sdk prakuschan$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin15]


Philipps-MacBook-Pro:mobile-sdk prakuschan$ gem list CF
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
CFPropertyList (2.3.3)
```

The xcodebuild -exportArchive command is executed in a shell script, and after a successful archive I get the following error:

```
** ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED **
2016-09-22 10:02:16.460 xcodebuild[10375:8369748] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/9y/r64c9wld0jx2yf3glsrzhhr00000gn/T/AppName_2016-09-22_10-02-16.456.xcdistributionlogs'.
2016-09-22 10:02:18.228 xcodebuild[10375:8369748] [MT] IDEDistribution: Step failed: <IDEDistributionThinningStep: 0x7fe435f9dfb0>: Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=14 "No applicable devices found." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No applicable devices found.}
error: exportArchive: No applicable devices found.
Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=14 "No applicable devices found." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No applicable devices found.}
** EXPORT FAILED **
```

When looking into the xcdistributionlogs, the IDEDistribution.standard.log contains the following lines at the very end:

```
2016-09-22 08:02:18 +0000 [MT] /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool exited with a signal 6
2016-09-22 08:02:18 +0000 [MT] ipatool JSON: (null)
```

I don't know if it is valuable, but this is the path to ipatool:

```
2016-09-22 08:02:17 +0000 [MT] Running /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool
```

Any help is highly appreciated. I already tried many suggestions found on google, but found no solution yet.

Comment: I have the same probleme since we have update to Xcode 8 on our Build server. I have search at the web and could not find an awnser. so i have create an bugreport and send it to apple i hope they will give me an awnser to fix the problem then i will post it here.

Comment: @Zeropointer any response from Apple folks?

Comment: I tried a post on the Apple dev forum (https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/182955), but they didn't even approve my thread since a week. Doesn't seem that they take it serious at all.
In the meanwhile I found that freshly created Xcode project files build without problems, so I made the effort to transfer all settings and files of our app into a new project, and it worked. Maybe this helps some of you as a work-around.

Comment: @Philipp I have also tryed to create a new Xcode Project and found the problem. After adding my third party frameworks one by one i have found the problem. It was a old *.framework that was build with XCode 7 when i add this library i get the error on Export. So i contact the Framework builder for getting a new version.

Comment: @Zeropointer are you sure that it was the same error (No applicable devices found) you got when you added the Framework? We searched a lot to see what can cause this issue, and so far it seems that this error (No applicable devices found) is related to something in Xcode project config, it's just not clear to what.

Comment: @ViktorBenei yes when i add this old framework i get the error "No applicable device found" when i remove it i can export the app.

Comment: Strange.. thanks for the info @Zeropointer !

Comment: I had the same problem and managed to fixed it by setting Enable bitcode to false (tmp solution)

Comment: @spafrou bitcode was already false at my project

Answer (score 10):

I was seeing the same issue. After searching through:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13446

And elsewhere for Xcode 7 similar issues. I realized this one is unique. You can fix it if you tweak the ipatool script in Xcode 8.

```
sudo vi /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool
```

And comment out this one line:

```
# Check the artwork idiom.
#return nil,"the device doesn't support the app's UIDeviceFamily" unless (deviceTraits.supportedIdioms & bundle.supportedIdioms).size > 0
```

Found via sleuthing the ipatool command in:

```
/var/folders/.../IDEDistribution.standard.log
```

You can search for these via:

```
$ sudo find /private/var -name "*.xcdistributionlogs"
```

---

Relevant detail / debugging steps: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/8737

Comment: thank you for your tipp i have tryed it but it does not work. But i have found the reason why my Export fails in the IDEDistribution.standard.log

Comment: @ViktorBenei here are my logs [MT] /Applications/Xcode_8.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool exited with 1
2016-10-03 07:45:38 +0000 [MT] ipatool JSON: {
    alerts =     ({
            code = 0;
            description = "Info.plist of \MyApp.app/Frameworks/TheFramework.framework/Resources\U201d specifies a non-existent file for the CFBundleExecutable key";
            info =             {
            };
            level = ERROR;
            type = "malformed-payload";
        }
    );

Comment: Cool! It appears that debugging ipatool via that log IDEDistribution.standard.log is useful in different circumstances. That's my main takeaway. Thank goodness we can all just read the Ruby file if needed.

Comment: That is still a symptom, but very useful information nevertheless. In my case the root cause for the problem was use of google-cast-sdk and this bug: https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=954

Comment: @Zeropointer where is the location of `IDEDistribution.standard.log`?

Answer (score 5):

We had the same issue `"No applicable devices found"` after running

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath ../bin/archive/GetSocialTestApp.xcarchive -exportPath ../bin/ -exportOptionsPlist ../../scripts/exportOptions.plist
```

**Working solution**: wrap `xcodebuild` with `xcbuild-safe.sh` from [fastlane repo](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/gym/lib/assets/wrap_xcodebuild/xcbuild-safe.sh). Detailed solution described [here](https://openradar.appspot.com/28726736).

As appeared, the problem was caused by `rvm` environment variables, `xcbuild-safe.sh` cleans them before executing `xcodebuild`.

**Not working** solutions that we tried:

- modify `ipatool` script as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39814611/731775)
- downgrade to ruby 2.0.0
- install ruby gems `CFPropertyList`, `sqlite3` that `ipatool` was complaining about

Comment: Worked for us as well. We wanted to use this wrapper inside Fastlane custom action. Ended up getting path to `xcbuild-safe.sh` like so: 
`requrie "gym"`
 `xcbuild_safe ||= File.join(Gym::ROOT, "lib/assets/wrap_xcodebuild/xcbuild-safe.sh")`

Comment: Worked for us too. Seems it was an rvm problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the `Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=14 "No applicable devices found."` with my enterprise project when including a third party framework. My `exportOptionsPlist` file contained the `compileBitcode=NO` entry but the project itself still had bitcode on.

I also used the log at `/var/folders/.../IDEDistribution.standard.log` and found a clearer error that lead me to the solution.

More info: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2432/_index.html

Answer (score 2):

Copy following and add it to end of your ~/.bashrc (~/.zshrc if you are using ZSH). **and quit the terminal and start it again (must)**.

```
unset RUBYLIB
unset RUBYOPT
unset BUNDLE_BIN_PATH
unset _ORIGINAL_GEM_PATH
unset BUNDLE_GEMFILE
unset GEM_HOME
unset GEM_PATH
```

FYI:

Since Xcode has a dependency to 2 external gems: sqlite and CFPropertyList
More information https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/6495

We have to unset those variables for rbenv, rvm and when the user uses bundler
Even if we do not use rbenv in some environments such as CircleCI,
We also need to unset GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH explicitly.
More information https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/627

Comment: This fixed it for me in Jenkins in an sh call.

Answer (score 1):

That's it! Set the `bitcode = no` ,the error got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

@Tom Harada answers worked for me but I wanted to find what was causing the default `ipatool` to break.

It was the Google Cast 3.2 SDK, which was missing an entry it the plist framework. Updating it to 3.3 solved the export issue.

Refs: 
https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=954
https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/6223#issuecomment-267343853

Answer (score 0):

My build script have the same problem, and I check some framework that I added. There is a framework that include a plist file(the name is the same as Info.plist). So, I delete the Info.plist file, the build script work fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had a same issue with XCode 8.2.1

In my case the issue was reproducing on exporting an archive for either adhoc or appstore distribution with the following export info plist

```
<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd>
<plist version=1.0>
<dict>
        <key>teamID</key>
        <string>TEAMID</string>
        <key>method</key>
        <string>ad-hoc</string> # or `app-store`
        <key>uploadSymbols</key>
        <true/>
        <key>compileBitcode</key>
        <false/>
        <key>uploadBitcode</key>
        <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

It turned out that one of the linked frameworks was compiled using bitcode. This was pointed out from the xcode export log: 
`IDEDistribution.stadard.log`:

```
error: Failed to verify bitcode in YandexMapKit.framework/YandexMapKit:
error: Bundle only contains bitcode-marker /var/folders/zb/ftpjx10s547ddmzm_ybqdm51xdv_t7/T/IDEDistributionThinningStep.NKQ/Payload/Avito.app/Frameworks/YandexMapKit.framework/YandexMapKit (armv7)
```

I had to manually recompile the `YandexMapKit` project into `iphoneos`- and `iphonesimulator`- frameworks and merge them into a universal framework

Answer (score 0):

At first, you need to check that if you have installed sqlite3 and CFPropertyList with gem on your mac.
Use these commands to review the result in your terminal:

- `gem list | grep sqlite3`
- `gem list | grep CFPropertyList`

if you print nothing, then you have to install them with sudo

- `sudo gem install sqlite3`
- `sudo gem install CFPropertyList`